# Dependency Injection on .net framework 4.7 project

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I Try to  set up a Dependency injection in my project, I already make the injection in my controller class like this :

```
 private IMapper1<string,HomeViewModel> _homeMapper;

 public HomeController(HomeViewModelMapper homeViewModelMapper)
 {
     _homeMapper = homeViewModelMapper != null ? homeViewModelMapper : throw new ArgumentNullException( nameof (homeViewModelMapper));
 }

 public HomeController() { }

 public ActionResult Index()
 {
     var viewModel = _homeMapper.Map("test");
     return View(viewModel);
 }
```

And i deported my dependency configuration class in a IOC class like this :

```
public class IOC
{
    public void ConfigureServices (IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IMapper1<string,HomeViewModel>, HomeViewModelMapper>();
    }
}
```

but where do i call the function 'ConfigureServices' of the IOC class ?
However, it seems the IOC class inherit from an interface but what interface ?

I try to call the function 'ConfigureServices' in the globalAsax.cs class ( it seems that other function was called in this class) like this :

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        IOC.ConfigureServices(services);
    }
```

but it's not working, the function wait an object reference of services.

May i have forgot a step ? what do wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

.NET Framework 4.7 is pretty old, so I'm not sure I remember this correctly, but IIRC you need to implement [IControllerFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dd470353(v=vs.100)) for ASP.NET MVC or [IHttpControllerActivator for Web API](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/09/28/DependencyInjectionandLifetimeManagementwithASP.NETWebAPI).

Then you need to register those custom interfaces like

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(myControllerFactory);
```

for MVC or

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(
    typeof(IHttpControllerActivator),
    new myCompositionRoot());
```

for Web API.

That said, why .NET framework 4.7?

There may be good reasons that you can't migrate to .NET Core, but even so, you should be able to upgrade to .NET framework 4.8.1.

Comment: Thank for your reply.
Usualy I work on Sitecore project and i use the sitecore Dependency injection system and the cms do the rest but in this case I will soon be working on a project in .net 4.7, i don't think a migration was possible and like you said it's pretty old so  I'm doing a little personal refresher, I try your answer later